# Code first custom linking table queries using the wrong column name

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am currently trying to implement a customised code-first linking table that references the same entity twice - essentially allowing a `Person` entity to have a list of associated `Person` entities. The classes look like so:

```
[Table("person")]
public class Person : BaseEntity, IEntityInterface
{
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string GivenName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string MiddleNames { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    public List<PersonPerson> Persons { get; set; }

    <other columns>
}

[Table("personperson")]
public class PersonPerson : BaseEntitiesObject
{
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person_ID")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OtherPerson_ID")]
    public virtual Person OtherPerson { get; set; }

    [Column("Person_ID")]
    public Guid Person_ID { get; set; }

    [Column("OtherPerson_ID")]
    public Guid OtherPerson_ID { get; set; }

    <more columns>
}
```

This works just fine for creating the link - the left side ID ends up in `Person_ID` and the right side in `OtherPerson_ID`, and the link is happily established. However, whenever a `Person` object is queried from the database the query ends up looking like this:

```
SELECT
1 AS `C1`, 
`Extent1`.`ID`, 
`Extent1`.`Type`, 
`Extent1`.`Person_ID`, 
`Extent1`.`OtherPerson_ID`, 
`Extent1`.`Jurisdiction`, 
`Extent1`.`EffectiveDate`, 
`Extent1`.`ExpiryDate`, 
`Extent1`.`Created`, 
`Extent1`.`CreatedBy`, 
`Extent1`.`Updated`, 
`Extent1`.`UpdatedBy`, 
`Extent1`.`Source`, 
`Extent1`.`Person_ID1`
FROM `personperson` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE (`Extent1`.`Person_ID1` IS NOT NULL) AND (`Extent1`.`Person_ID1` = @EntityKeyValue1)
```

It is trying to find the left hand ID in `Person_ID1` despite the attributes telling it which column to use for the foreign key relationship and explicitly stating what that column's name should be. The only place this happens is where a linking table is referencing the same entity twice, so I figure that has something to do with it, but I'm at a loss to know what to do about it.

Comment: What is Person_ID**1** ?

Comment: @Fabiano that is the mysterious extra column that EF is adding when it makes the query. So "what is Person_ID1?" That's exactly the question I asked when I started encountering this problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *two* `Person` reference navigation properties in `PersonPerson` entity (hence *two* relationships), but *single* collection navigation property in `Person` class.

Without additional data annotations/fluent configuration EF does not know to which of the two relationships should map the collection, so by convention it silently assumes a *third* (!) unidirectional (i.e. with collection only) relationship, hence the additional column you see in the SQL query.

Anytime you have more than one relationship between two entities, you need to configure (map) them properly. Normally it's possible to use `InverseProperty` data annotation, but such relationships introduce the *multiple cascade path* problem, and since `one-to-many` relationships by default have cascade delete om, you really need to use fluent configuration for both mapping and turning the cascade delete off.

Here is the configuration for your model:

```
// first relationship
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonPerson>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Person)
    .WithMany(e => e.Persons)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.Person_ID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

// second relationship        
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonPerson>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.OtherPerson)
    .WithMany() // no corresponding collection
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.OtherPerson_ID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

In case you add second collection to `Person`, make sure to update the mapping correctly by specifying it inside the second `WithMany`.

Note that turning cascade delete off for the both relationships is not strongly necessary. It will sufficient to turn it off just for one of them (in your case, most likely for the second).

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly the step I needed. I added those relationship mappings and everything started working.